# Meu usuário não manipula arquivos gerados no PHP

Tags: php, linux, file-permission

Ola, estou com um problema chato com permissões não entendo o motivo de meu usuario não ter permissões sobre arquivos criados pelo "php"

Vamos lá
meu user `foo` pertence aos seguintes grupos:

```
adm cdrom sudo dip www-data plugdev lpadmin sambashare laravel
```

grupos do www-data

```
www-data : www-data laravel
```

Ele já esta no grupo www-data

Quando o php gera algum arquivo, por exemplo uma pasta zipada, ou até mesmo arquivos que ele baixa do aws-s3 eles vem

```
wwww-data:www-data
```

Estes arquivos minha IDE por exemplo não consegue apagar, se eu tentar pelo terminal também não consigo.
Ja tentei mudar o projeto para `foo:laravel` mas todo novo arquivo ele cria com  `www-data:www-data`

Quando eu gero algo pelo laravel por exemplo um log ou algum cache vem

```
foo:laravel
```

Que ai consigo alterar normalmente

(laravel é um grupo que criei testando para ver se resolvo esse problema de permissão)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deve colocar chmod 775 para os arquivos criados pelo www-data, assim users do mesmo grupo poderão realizar alterações.
Se tiver acesso de root no server você pode colocar o valor padrão da permissão dos arquivos criados pelo www-data:

Para debian, ubuntu

```
echo "umask 002" >> /etc/apache2/envvars
service apache2 restart
```

Para rhel, centos:

```
echo "umask 002" >> /etc/sysconfig/httpd
service httpd restart
```

Comment: é no meu computador, não possuo esse arquivo que mencionou não.

Comment: Após sua edição deu certo